# How to compile *.hs to llvm ir (*.ll) using GHC compiler?

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc

I tried

```
ghc -fllvm -pgmlo -pgmlc -ddump-llvm src.hs
```

and

```
ghc -fllvm -pgmlo -pgmlc -keep-llvm-files src.hs
```

opt and llc (3.5.1 version) are in PATH

But I haven't found any llvm ir after I executed commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably GHC didn't recompile your program since the program hadn't changed since you last ran GHC. This seems likely since `-pgmlo -pgmlc` means "use `-pgmlc` as the LLVM optimizer" which is not going to work. Just run

```
ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files -fforce-recomp src.hs
```

(or manually modify `src.hs` and recompile it).

Comment: Force recompilation helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) `-pgm[letter]` - use this command if you only compiling into C code(in your case if you compiling without `-fllvm` flag)

2) `-keep-llvm-files` - find .ll files in current directory, otherwise try to find them in /tmp directory(i saw this bug somewhere)

3) `ghc` works only with llvm 3.5

Comment: ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files src.hs
and replacing v 3.5.1 opt and llc with v 3.5.0 ones didn't help.

Comment: GHC works with any version of LLVM, as far as I'm aware. If the files are not named `opt` and `llc`, but rather something like `opt-3.5` and `llc-3.5`, then you may need to add the options `-pgmlo opt-3.5 -pgmlc llc-3.5`.

Comment: i meant that ghc version ⩽ 7.8 works only with llvm which version is ⩽ 3.5